# Azure Migrate Mobility service agent issues

Tags: azure-migrate

I'm trying to migrate a server over to Azure and got stuck on the Mobility service agent installation on the source machine.

The installation is failing so the source server is not registering to the Migrate appliance therefore not showing up on the VM available for replication list.

[image]

I couldn't;t find much information about the error online so decided to reach out to the community.

I tried both GUI and CLI installations of the Mobility services agent.

The installation is failing with the error 'Setup was unable to stop required services' on the source server.

When checking on Azure, the source VM not showing up on the replication list.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys.

Rebooted the source VM and uninstalled the agent, then installed again using cmd as admin.

Not sure what did the trick, but the installation completed successfully.

[Installation completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uj4S.png)